# (Batch) How to recursively delete all files/folders in a directory except those with a leading .?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, pattern-matching

I have a directory, `src`. I want to recursively delete all of its contents except for files (`.gitignore`, ...) and folders (`.git`, `.vscode`, ...) whose names begin with `.`. Matching that pattern in subdirectories is neither necessary nor harmful.

What is the cleanest way to do this in a batch file?

Comment: What happens if there is a `.` file or directory within a non-`.` directory?

Comment: It shouldn't matter one way or the other, in my case. I don't believe any such files can exist in my environment. I suppose preservation would be better.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Check out using pattern [`.*`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)...

Comment: The inversion, basically.
`for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s /a ".*"') do echo %%i`
gets the files I want to exclude, but I don't know how to exclude them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

:: step 1 : delete all files NOT starting "."

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 ECHO %%~nxa|FINDSTR /b /L "." >nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO(DEL "%%a"
)

:: step 2 : delete all directories NOT starting "."

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /ad "%sourcedir%\*" ^|sort /r'
 ) DO (
 ECHO %%~nxa|FINDSTR /b /L "." >nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO(RD "%%a"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

The required RD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(RD` to `RD` to actually delete the directories.

for each filename in the entire subtree, see whether it starts with `.`, setting `errorlevel` to non-0 if not and hence delete the file.

Once this has been done, repeat the operation with directorynames, but sort the names found in reverse so that a subdirectoryname of any directory will appear before the directoryname. *Attempt* to remove the directory with an `rd` - it will remain if it contains files or subdirectories (which implicitly will start `.`). Append `2>nul` to the `rd` line to suppress error messages (where the directory cannot be removed as it still contains files/subdirectories)

Comment: Just had to remove the `/s` in `dir` for my purposes, but this works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to exclude folders with a leading dot (on a per folder base):

```
for /f "tokens=*eol=." %%A in ('dir /B /AD') do Echo=%%A
```

This doesn't affect folder names containing dots at other positions.

A relatively slow variant recursing all folders and using findstr to filter all folders containing `\.` both chars need escaping with a backslash

```
for /r /D %%A in (*) do @echo %%A|findstr /V "\\\."
```